# Strip string values in a dictionary and convert it to a float. Values contain numbers separated by space

Tags: python, string, dictionary

I have a dictionary setup with the following data:

[image: image of dictionary with values]

where its values are a list of **strings**:

```
['2 1 0\n', '3 0 1\n', '4 0 3\n' .... ]   
['-3.85995e-17  1.26224e+00  2.63053e-01\n']
```

Is there a way I can convert the values into a list of **floats** without having to use too many loops?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to find a library that handles such data to do it for you, I'm not aware of any native python method to convert a string into a list of floats.
If you're looking to save space, it'd probably just be easiest to write your own function that takes one of your values and returns a list of floats.

For example:

```
def string_to_float_list(string):
    split = string.strip().split(" ")
    floats = []    
    for s in split:
        if len(s) == 0:
            continue
        floats.append(float(s.strip()))
    return floats
```

Takes input:

```
string = '-3.85995e-17  1.26224e+00  2.63053e-01\n'
```

Gives output:

```
[-3.85995e-17, 1.26224, 0.263053]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Xorgon!

I also tried using list comprehensions as follows:

```
Connectivity = ['2 1 0\n', '3 0 1\n', '4 0 3\n']

aaa = [k.strip() for k in Connectivity]   
bbb =  [k.split() for k in aaa]
ccc = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in bbb]
```

But is there a faster way? The reason being that the variable Connectivity would contain about 5million items